# Upgraded to Rails 5, Issue when pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I just upgraded my project to 5.1.4 and i fixed all the issues on local host. I am now pushing to my staging environment and im getting this error when pushing to Heroku.

```
remote:        Removing activerecord-import (0.19.1)
remote:        Removing actionmailer (4.2.3)
remote: -----> Installing node-v6.11.1-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     LoadError: cannot load such file -- netaddr
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/email_address-0.1.7/lib/email_address/exchanger.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/email_address-0.1.7/lib/email_address.rb:5:in `<module:EmailAddress>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/email_address-0.1.7/lib/email_address.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/Rakefile:4:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_1857c4cf922c4c07f51dada80913d8f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `load'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `<main>'
remote:  !
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:106:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
remote: ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote: and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote: rake aborted!
```

I tried running `bundle exec rake -P` like it suggests and i get no errors. Anyone know what this issue is or how i can start troubleshooting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to look at your `/config/application.rb:8`. The issue is probably there and it may be about `netaddr` file.

For troubleshooting you may execute `rails console`. It should throw you an error while with `rails server` it may ignore the errors in the code until it execute exactly that code.

Comment: thanks, the issue was my gem 'email_address' was utilizing 'netaddr' and didn't support the latest version, so i had to downgrade 'netaddr' to 1.5.1